# Ubuntu browsers trying to make me connect via a proxy that isn't available, how do I stop it wanting to connect to it?

Tags: firefox, proxy

I recently updated my computer and now it wont' let me go online. It keeps coming up with the error message;

Cannot connect to proxy (slb-webcache.hull.ac.uk).

How do I get rid of it's proxy associations?

Answer (score 1):

To disable proxy open `Preferences` in `Edit` menu, go to `Advanced` -> `Network` tab -> `Connection settings`, then select `No proxy`.

The screenshots bellow are not in english but can help you figure out what to do:

[image: Preferences / Advanced / Network]

[image: Check "No proxy"]